# SugarCRM or Vtiger?

Tags: crm, sugarcrm, vtiger

I'm working on deploying a CRM in a University, the software to deploy has to be open source.
My research lead me to SugarCRM Community Edition, however, this edition lack of reporting and  seems to be really hard to tailor to specific needs.

thus, i'm considering to use vtiger.

What's your advice, regarding a mid-size project.
**Do you recommand to use SugarCRM, Vtiger or another software?**

Comment: SuiteCRM is SugarCRM supercharged. It's SugarCRM Community Edition with Products, Quotes, Contracts, Projects, Reporting, Teams, Workflow, Portal, Maps, Events, greatly improved Cases and enhanced Search. It's completely open source and free to download.

https://suitecrm.com/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are well versed in CSS and can tailor vTiger to look a little better, then it might be a viable solution for you.

However, I would personally highly recommend SugarCRM. It is much easier to maintain and has a much larger community. Plus, you can look into the Enhanced Search Plugin, The Kinamu Reporting tool and the Zucker reports plugin to help fulfill your needs for a reporting tool. However, they are both free. I would just download them both and check into the free plugins on sugarforge and then base my decision on your findings there.

Hope this helps!

Comment: We've finally choosen to use CiviCRM which is a drupal extension that provide CRM features for charities, just what we wanted.
Thank for the answer anyways.

Answer (score 3):

I would also recommend sugarCRM because of the larger community and availability of third party plug ins, having worked with both i can say that sugarCRM's studio gives you a bit more flexibility. There are also many plug ins; I would recomend the ModernAqua theme to improve look and feel.

I'll give you a warning however, sugarCRM is not always nice to work with. Its code is poorly documented and maintainance is a big hastle. upgrading with custom code is still error prone through version 6.x despite what they say and changes will be overwritten by the module builder.

So in short, go with Sugar but think carefully before customizing it too much because it can be a pain to maintain.

Answer (score 3):

Unlike others, I am recommending vtiger CRM. The community with vtiger isn't small and if you are a true OpenSource lover then you should definitely use vtiger as it comes with no commercial version etc.

There is a number of available modules in the exchange available at [vTiger](http://www.vtiger.com). Also, a number of mobile apps etc are available too.

CSS proficiency? I don't think that is required at all. We are using vtiger out of the box and the look and feel is as good as you need. There is MailChimp integration etc available too if you are into marketing automation.

Answer (score 1):

Its better to use SugarCRM Professional Edition. In this already Report Module is in Built

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I recommend SugarCRM too. Vtiger has a much smaller community and for Sugar there are modules available for almost any scenario.